# Want ToggleBotton to NOT show ON/OFF text

Tags: android, xml, toggle

Im trying to make my ToggleBotton to NOT show the ON/OFF cause I'm using a backround of Green/Red that show if it's on or off and the text just messes things up..

Thank you.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
    android:checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just setting the *text* for **On** and **Off** to be an empty string like

```
android:textOff=""
android:textOn=""
```

Comment: Yeah that did it.. Not much of a clever way but it does it :) Funny thing is that i tried it before asking and for some reson it didn't work. Guess you got the touch. Better I go to sleep, Thanks a lot.